# PHP - Unknown Column in Array Where clause error

Tags: php, mysql

I have dropdown menus wich contains name of players and opposition team. When user picks team for opposition to play against he clicks the submit button and isset function is triggered where the data from the dropdown menus will be captured and uploaded to the database.

It is simple enough but I've got what I guess is a syntax error. I get the message in the title when page is opened. I've been trying to fix this with no luck. If someone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

```
 if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $player_ids = array_map('intval', $_REQUEST['players']);
    $opponents_id = $_REQUEST['players'];

    var_dump($opponents_id);

    $query = 'SELECT `name`, `position` 
        FROM `player_info` 
        WHERE `player_id` IN (' . implode(',', $player_ids) . ')';

    $return_names = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($return_names) ) 
        {
            $selected[] = $row['name'];
            $position[] = $row['position'];
        }

    $query = ("SELECT `fixture_id` 
            FROM `fixtures`
            WHERE `fixture_id` = $opponents_id"); 

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $fixture_id[] = $row['fixture_id']; 
            }
```

Comment: The problem is in the second query

Comment: Is this a typo? `$qury`. In line `$result = mysql_query($qury) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: try echoing $query, and put die(0); before $result statement.
and try to run echoed $query result in phpMyadmin. You will get to know what went wrong.

Comment: $qury is a typo well spotted

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the problem: `$qury`

```
$result = mysql_query($qury) or die(mysql_error());
```

Change to:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = ("SELECT `fixture_id` 
 ^ See Here
            FROM `fixtures`
            WHERE `fixture_id` = $opponents_id"); 

            $result = mysql_query($qury)                                    
                                   ^ See here
```

You have mistakenly typed wrong variable in `mysql_query`.